React Native Expo Library [TypeError: Network request failed] error only on Android
I am using
"expo": "~51.0.28",
"react-native": "0.74.5",

and when I try to fetch method in the giving code I am getting an error network request error.IOS working fine but when it comes to the android I am getting error. What can it be the reason if you help I m glad that I m stuck on this about a week.
I'm using SQL server and my api is public certificated SSL.
I am running on development build.
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" this didnt help what else can be solve the problem.
export const login = createAsyncThunk("user/login", async ({email, password}, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      console.log(email);
      console.log(password);
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://trendpiyasaapi.pazaryericonverter.com/v1/api/Auth/login/",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
          }),
        }
      );
  
      console.log("58. line login: ", response);
  
      const json = await response.json();
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        return rejectWithValue(json); 
      }
      const accessToken = json.data.accessToken;
      console.log(accessToken, "Access token from login");

      await AsyncStorage.setItem("UserData", accessToken);
  
      console.log("70. line login function:",json);
      return json;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("line 72 userSlice:", err);
      return rejectWithValue({ message: "Network Error" }); // Handle network errors
    }
  });

